# How to load user defined content to be used in a template?

Tags: macros

I'm writing a template which uses the `report` class and customizes the typesetting with several packages. I'm defining some data in a separate `user-data.tex` file which is loaded just after `documentclass`:

```
\def\thesis{Master} %<PhD> or <Master>
\def\thesistitle{The title of the thesis}
\def\author{AName AFirst ASecond}
\def\authormail{aname@univ.edu}
\def\school{Master and Doctoral School}
\def\date{City, month year}
\def\logo-university{univ.pdf}
```

Those variables/constants are used to provide two different titlepages, to be included in the footer with `titlesec`, or used by the user at any time.

Is it ok to do it like that (using just `\def`)? Or should I use `\global`, `\newcommand`... or any other ? Would you place them in any other format rather than plain `tex`?

---

After the comments, I changed to `\newcommand*` and renamed some of the macros:

```
\newcommand*\thesis{Master} %<PhD> or <Master>
\newcommand*\thesistitle{The title of the thesis}
\newcommand*\authors{AName AFirst ASecond}
\newcommand*\authorsmail{aname@univ.edu}
\newcommand*\school{Master and Doctoral School}
\newcommand*\titledate{City, month year}
\newcommand*\university{univ.pdf}
```

---

After the answer by @Andrew, I'm using

```
\providecommand*\@school{No SCHOOL defined}
\newcommand*\School[1]{\renewcommand*\@school{#1}}
```

just in the beginning of the package, to let the user either define `\newcommand*\@school{Something}` before loading it, or `\School{Something}` after doing so.

---

As @barbara guessed, I moved the template to a `*.sty` which I'm loading as a package:

mypkg.sty

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesPackage{mypkg}

%If not previously defined, default value applied
\providecommand*{\@mythesis}{No THESIS TYPE defined}
\providecommand*{\@myauthor}{No AUTHOR defined}
%Command to modify the field at any point after this
\newcommand*\MyThesis[1]{\renewcommand*\@mythesis{#1}}
\newcommand*\MyAuthor[1]{\renewcommand*\@myauthor{#1}}
%Command to access the field
\newcommand*\showDF[1]{\csname @#1\endcsname}

%The content may be supplied in a separate file with \Thesis
\@input{data.dat}

\endinput
```

main.tex

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,11pt,twoside,openright]{report}

% A field may defined before loading the package
\makeatletter
\newcommand\@mythesis{My title before loading}
\makeatother
%If it not defined, the package does it
\usepackage{mypkg}

\begin{document}

% The variable may be directly accessed
\makeatletter\@mythesis\makeatother
% The content may be rewritten
\MyThesis{PhD}
% Reading with the provided command
\showDF{mythesis}
\showDF{myauthor}

\end{document}
```

It works. The user can define the content prior to loading the package, or either in a separate file or at any point after doing so with a 'helper command'. However, I'd like to:

-Use a command to automatically define the commands associated to a field. New question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203026/how-to-use-csname-expandafter-csuse-namedef).

-Give the user the ability to give the field as an option when loading the package. I tried with `xkeyval`:

```
\define@key{fam}{thesis}[Master]{\Thesis{#1}}
\ProcessOptionsX<fam>
```

changing the loading in the main file to:

```
\usepackage[thesis=PhD]{mypkg}
```

The above code works, except for the fields which have more than a word, since the spaces between them are removed. How can I make it work with, i.e. `\usepackage[title=A title with several words]{mypkg}`. I tried with `{A title with several words}` and `"A title with several words"` but It doesn't work.

[It can not be made](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56486/spaces-in-pfgopts-options)

---

Using the approach in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203513/using-forcsvlist-with-macros-that-take-more-than-one-argument) answer, I have now this 'factory' function to create all the commands at once:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\forcsvlistargs[2]{ \expandafter\providecommand\csname \detokenize{#1}aux\endcsname[1]{
 \csname \detokenize{#1}\endcsname##1\relax}
 \forcsvlist{\csname \detokenize{#1}aux\endcsname}{#2}
}
\newcommand\newDF[2]{ \expandafter\providecommand\csname th#1\endcsname{No \MakeUppercase{#2} defined}
 \expandafter\newcommand\csname TH#2\endcsname[1]{\expandafter\renewcommand\csname th#1\endcsname{##1}} }

\forcsvlistargs{newDF}{{{typ}{type}}, {{date}{date}}, {{tit}{title}}, {{sch}{school}}, 
{{aut}{author}}, {{eaut}{eauthor}} }
```

Comment: fairly trivial comment -- hyphens aren't permitted in command names, so `\logo-university` would be better with a different name.

Comment: one problem with using `\def` is that you don't get warned about overwriting existing commands eg `\author` and `\date`

Comment: Another thing to consider is _if_ you want to allow a user to define these as `\newcommands` _before_ your file is loaded. If so, I'd use `\providecommand`.  Otherwise they have to use `\renewcommand` _after_ the file is loaded.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\catcode`-=11\def\logo-university\includegraphics{logo}` ;-) oh the markup fails, but you get the point

Comment: @1010011010 -- yes, you *can* do that, but if you have other hyphens in the file, things are likely to go awry in ways you didn't foresee.

Comment: the file being provided is called a "template" in the question.  given that one of the commands defined contains an `@` sign, and is thus an "internal" command, it might be useful to point out that the "template" file will be named either `*.cls` or `*.sty`, and accessed by `\documentclass` or `\usepackage`.  otherwise, additional measures are needed to avoid unwanted error messages.

Comment: That's correct. However, I defined the command `\showDF` to let the user have easy acces to the fields. Did you mean that? I suppose I could just remove the `@`, but I think it's better to use it, since it will prevent the user from overwritting just with `\def`. BTW, I added a MWE exposing the usage as a package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have some (internal) classes that do something like this. What I do is first define a command like:

```
\newcommand\School[1]{\def\@school{#1}}
```

so that the "user" can use `\School{My wonderful school}` to overwrite the defaults.  Internally, the class uses `\@school` whenever it needs to print the name of the school.

Next, if this is reasonable I have the class set a reasonable default for the school by having a line like

```
\School{My Wonderful School}
```

in the class. In fact, it is probably better form to use

```
\providescommand\@school{My Wonderful School}
```

although using the "helper command" is clearer, I think.

One place where I use this is for tutorial sheets where it happens that many of these variables depend on something else. For these cases I define an option to the class for setting all of these variables in one hit. So the "user" starts their file with

```
\documentclass[somecourse,solutions]{mytutorials}
```

and then inside `mytutorials.cls` I have

```
\DeclareOption{somecourse}{
  \CourseName{An exciting counrse}
  \Semester{Semester 2}
  \CourseNumber{Math 987123}
}
\DeclareOption{solutions}{
    ...
}
```

To process all of the options you need something like:

```
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
\ProcessOptions
```

This allows me to piggyback off `article.cls` and pass it options that are not defined in my file.

Finally, depending on your use-case, you might want to automatically load a set of defaults from a file in the current directory. If you use `\include` or `\input` then you will run into problems when the file does not exist. Instead you can use `\@input` inside your class file:

```
\@input{defaults.dat}
```

This will load the file "defaults.dat" if it exists and, otherwise, do nothing. This file will be included as is, so there is a danger in using this trick because if the file contains garbage everything breaks. Of course,  to cover the cases when this file does not exist, you need to set reasonable defaults.

(Btw, for your own internal variables there is really no harm in using `\def` -- and it is easier too. Of course, you should first make sure that you are not overwriting anything else!)

Comment: Thanks a lot for you answer. As you can see, I edited the question and took your approach into account. However, when trying to pass the fields as options of the package (not a class in my case, although I suppose there's no much difference) the spaces between words disappear. In the example you provided you use single-word keys. Would you mind having a look at the edited question?

Comment: @U.Martinez-Corral There seem to be three variations for using keys: [xkeyval](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval), [kvoptions](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/kvoptions) and [pgfopts](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfopts). None of them support spaces in the keys, so I think that you are out of luck. The way that I cope with this is that I have a single keyword (without spaces) that then sets multiword parameter (with spaces).

Comment: I was afraid of hearing that... but have to cope with it :D. Aniway, it is already much 'easier' than it was when I did the question! On the other hand, have you ever tried with `\csname` to define several commands at once?

Comment: I should have added that I have not ever used keys, so even though I did not find a way of allowing spaces perhaps there is one. For your second question, instead of `\csname...\endcsname` you can also use the LaTeX primitives `\@namedef`and `\@nameuse` - these both just wrap the corresponding TeX commands. The [etoolbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package provides many variations like `\csdef`, `\csuse`, ... These commands are both easier to read and easier to use.

Comment: I'm trying with `\providecommand\@nameuse{@#1}{No #2 defined}` and `\providecommand\csuse{@#1}{No #2 defined}`, but none of them work. `\expandafter\providecommand\csname @#1\endcsname{No {\MakeUppercase #2} defined}` works, but the `\MakeUppercase` has no effect. I would prefer not to use `@namedef` and `\csdef` since I'd like to check if those commands have been previously set.

Comment: You should ask this as another question:) I do not have time to write an answer now, but will later if no one else replies.

Comment: I've created a new question, added the link to this, and removed the corresponding part. Thanks again.