# Parse csv-list, function with >1 parameters as callback

Tags: macros, parsing, comma-separated-list

In my texts I have to deal with lists, whose items need to be formatted seperatly, i.e.:

`\funktion[3][]{T}--\funktion{S}--\funktion[3][7]{D}--\funktion{T}`

In `\funktion` which leads to `\emphsubsup` the formatting takes place and the optional parameters are handled.

How can I shorten this task by a function like `\funktionen`? I.e.:

`\funktionen{[3][]{T},{Sp},[3][{7,9,11}]{D},{T}}` or even better:

`\funktionen{[3][]T,Sp,[3][{7,9,11}]D,T}`

Each argument can contain more than 1 character, including comma!

I've tried it with `forcsvlist` from the `etoolbox` package, but it takes (of course) the whole value `[3][]{T}` as one single argument. Also I don't know how to realize the seperator `--`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage{etoolbox, xparse, fixltx2e, letltxmacro}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\subsup}{ o o m }{%
\IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \textsubscript{#1}#3\textsuperscript{#2}%
    }{%
    #3\textsuperscript{#1}}%
}{#3}%
}
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\emphsubsup}{ o o m }{\emph{\subsup[#1][#2]{#3}}}%same, only emphasized

\LetLtxMacro{\funktion}{\emphsubsup}

%test
\newcommand*{\funktionen}[1]{%
    \forcsvlist{\funktion}{#1}
}

\begin{document}

    \funktion[3][]{T}--\funktion{Sp}--\funktion[3][7,9,11]{D}--\funktion{T}

    \hskip1ex

    \funktionen{[3][]{T},{Sp},[3][{7,9,11}]{D},{T}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [This](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203513/using-forcsvlist-with-macros-that-take-more-than-one-argument) question about extending `forcsvtlist` to take more than one argument may be useful for you. It's not exactly what you want, but just have to add some braces around each group: `\forcsvlistargs{mycmd}{ {{1a}{1b}} , {{2a}{2b}} , {{3a}{3b}} }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you are really looking for parsing 'beyond' a document command (*i.e.* this isn't really standard LaTeX2e-style argument to a simple command) I'd be tempted to code the parser bit myself. Assuming you don't need to worry about nested `[`/`]` (in which case I guess you do need `xparse`) we can do it quite simply using a 'classical' look-ahead approach. I've done this in `expl3` but it could also be done easily using `\@ifnextchar`:

```
\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareDocumentCommand \funktionen { > { \SplitList { , } } m }
  {
    \musicman_parse:n {#1}
  }
\seq_new:N \l__musicman_parse_seq
\tl_new:N \l__musicman_tmp_tl
\cs_new_protected:Npn \musicman_parse:n #1
  {
    \group_begin:
      \seq_clear:N \l__musicman_parse_seq
      \tl_map_inline:nn {#1}
        {
          \tl_clear:N \l__musicman_tmp_tl
          \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF [ % ]
            { \__musicman_parse_auxi:w }
            { \__musicman_parse_auxiii:w }
          ##1 \q_stop
          \seq_put_right:NV \l__musicman_parse_seq \l__musicman_tmp_tl
        }
      \seq_use:Nn \l__musicman_parse_seq { -- }
    \group_end:
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__musicman_parse_auxi:w [ #1 ]
  {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__musicman_tmp_tl { \textsubscript {#1} }
    \peek_meaning_ignore_spaces:NTF [ % ]
      { \__musicman_parse_auxii:w }
      { \__musicman_parse_auxiii:w }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__musicman_parse_auxii:w [ #1 ] #2 \q_stop
  {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__musicman_tmp_tl
      {
        \exp_not:n {#2}
        \tl_if_blank:nF {#1} { \exp_not:n { \textsuperscript {#1} } }
      }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__musicman_parse_auxiii:w #1 \q_stop
  { \tl_set:Nn \l__musicman_tmp_tl {#1} }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\funktionen{[3][]{T},{Sp},[3][{7,9,11}]{D},{T}}

\end{document}
```

I've used a sequence to hold the 'partial' list of items as this makes it easy to insert the separators (`--`) without having to do any tests myself for 'end of list' or similar. One could instead use a hand-crafted mapping in this case, but unless performance is vital that tends to be less clear than the approach here.

For the `expl3` experts, I note that here we could use `\tl_if_head_eq_meaning:nNTF` instead of `\peek_meaning:NTF` as the argument has already been grabbed.

Comment: Thank you! Can you check my question update? Your code is pretty abstract which fits my needs more. I just have to use `\emph{\musicman_parse:n {#1}}` now in `\funktionen`. But the delimiter `--` is missing.

Comment: @musicman I didn't realise the `--` was required in the output :-) Fixed that, but I'm not sure what you mean about `\emph`.

Comment: Now it's working perfectly. Thx a lot. In some cases (tones) I need the whole string emphasized, in other cases (functions) normal. Hence one function with `\emph`, one without, no big deal. But one more little question, in case I need it. What's the code to print out `--` with surrounding spaces? line `\seq_use:Nn \l__musicman_parse_seq { -- }`

Comment: @musicman In `expl3` syntax, `~` is used to represent a space so `\seq_use:Nn \l__musicman_parse_seq { ~--~ }` or similar might be what you want (perhaps you ant thin spaces and/or control of breaking too: it depends on the use case).

Answer (score 4):

If you don't mind the function being executed inside a `TeX` group then you could try `pgffor`:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox, xparse, fixltx2e, pgffor}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\funktion}{ o o m }{%
\IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \textsubscript{#1}#3\textsuperscript{#2}%
    }{%
    #3\textsuperscript{#1}}%
}{#3}%
}

%test
\newcommand*{\funktionen}[1]{%%
  \foreach \args [count=\x]in {#1}{%
    \ifnum\x>1--\fi\expandafter\funktion\args%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\funktion[3][]{T}--\funktion{S}--\funktion[3][7]{D}--\funktion{T}
\hskip1ex

\funktionen{[3][]{T},{S},[3][7]{D},{T}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, a custom list parser is fairly straightforward:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}

\usepackage{etoolbox, xparse, fixltx2e}


\DeclareDocumentCommand{\funktion}{ o o m }{%
\IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \IfValueTF{#2}{%
    \textsubscript{#1}#3\textsuperscript{#2}%
    }{%
    #3\textsuperscript{#1}}%
}{#3}%
}

\newcommand*{\Funktionen}[1]{%
  \let\FunctionenNext=\relax%
  \FunctionenLoop#1,\FunctionenHalt,%
}
\def\FunctionenHalt{\FunctionenHalt}%
\def\FunctionenLoop#1,{%
  \def\tmp{#1}%
  \ifx\tmp\FunctionenHalt%
    \let\FunctionenNext=\relax%
  \else%
    \ifx\FunctionenNext\relax\else--\fi%
    \funktion#1%
    \let\FunctionenNext=\FunctionenLoop%
  \fi%
  \FunctionenNext%
}
\begin{document}

\funktion[3][]{T}--\funktion{S}--\funktion[3][7]{D}--\funktion{T}

\hskip1ex

\Funktionen{[3][]{T},{S},[3][7]{D},{T}}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same as before.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I figured out that my real life case is a bit more complex which leads to problems. If I use your code for example, only the first character becomes emphasized, but all need to be. Check my new MWE.

Comment: I've accepted Joseph Wrights answer, since it's pretty cool to use the strings without curly braces. Thx for you answer though :)

Answer (score 3):

The solution without need to any LaTeX package follows. After

```
\funktionen{[3][]T,Sp,[3][7,9,11]D,T}
```

you have stored the following content:

```
\funktion[3][]{T}--\funktion{Sp}--\funktion[3][7,9,11]{D}--\funktion{T}
```

in `\funktionenL` macro. You can execute it by simply running `\funktionenL`.

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\funktionen#1{\def\funktionenL{}\funktionenA#1,,}
\def\funktionenA{\let\tmpa=\relax \let\tmpb=\relax \futurelet\next\funktionenB}
\def\funktionenB{\ifx\next[\expandafter\funktionenC \else \expandafter\funktionenF \fi}
\def\funktionenC[#1]{\def\tmpa{#1}\futurelet\next\funktionenD}
\def\funktionenD{\ifx\next[\expandafter\funktionenE \else \expandafter\funktionenF \fi}
\def\funktionenE[#1]{\def\tmpb{#1}\funktionenF}
\def\funktionenF#1,{\ifx,#1,\else
   \ifx\funktionenL\empty \else \addto\funktionenL{--}\fi
   \addto\funktionenL{\funktion}%
   \ifx\tmpa\relax\else \funktionenG{\expandafter[\tmpa]}\fi
   \ifx\tmpb\relax\else \funktionenG{\expandafter[\tmpb]}\fi
   \addto\funktionenL{{#1}}%
   \expandafter\funktionenA
   \fi
}
\def\funktionenG{\expandafter\addto\expandafter\funktionenL\expandafter}

\funktionen{[3][]T,Sp,[3][7,9,11]D,T}

\message{\meaning\funktionenL}
```